# How to limit the number of phone that connect to the device via bluetooth?

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, bluez

The application scenario:

The android app connect to the embedded device via bluetooth and some data transfers between them. At every moment, only one app can control and send data to the embedded device.

The development environment:

linux, c/c++, bluez stack, cmdline tools like bluetoothctl.

Bluetooth 4.0 allows more than one slaves that can communicate with the master in a a Bluetooth piconet.

So how to limit the number of phones that connect to the embedded device?

Answer (score 2):

With Bluetooth 4.0, a slave can be connected to one master only. A master device, on the other hand, can have multiple slaves (e.g. in the piconet, your Android device can connect to 8 or more slaves, but if the slaves are 4.0 devices then they cannot be connected to another master).

The feature whereby one slave can be connected to more than one master was introduced in Bluetooth 4.1 and is called **LE Link Layer Topology**. Prior to this feature, a slave could have only one connection.

So, to answer your question, you don't need to do anything in order to limit the number of phones that can connect to your embedded device. Once a phone is connected, your embedded device will not be able to accept any other incoming BLE connection.

Finally, there is actually a way to ensure that your slave connects to one master only, regardless of what version of Bluetooth is being used. This is achieved by disabling adverts once you are in a connection. Advertising is the only way to accept incoming connections, and if your device is not advertising then it will not even be visible to remote devices.

For more information, please see Bluetooth Specification v5.1, Vol 6, Part B, Section 1.1 Link Layer States.

I hope this helps.